# Joining MySQL Tables dynamically

Tags: mysql, join, stored-procedures

i am writing a MySQL Stored Procedure which has to join a "base" table with other tables.
Which other table to join depends on a *field* in the base table.

This is the base table:

```
ID - Value - JoinValue - TableToJoin - FieldToJoin
---------------------------------------------------
 1 - Test  - aa        - tbl_test1   - test1field
 2 - Test2 - bb        - tbl_test2   - test2field
```

As Output, i wanna have:

```
ID - Value - ValueFromOtherTable
----------------------------------------------
aa  - Test  - ValueFromTBL_TEST1Field
bb  - Test2 - ValueFromTBL_TEST2Field
```

Is this somehow possible?
Somewhat like this maybe?

```
SELECT
 ID,
 Value,
 (SELECT @FieldToJoin FROM @TableToJoin AS t WHERE t.ID = @JoinValue) AS ValueFromOtherTable
FROM tbl_base;
```

Already tried some sort of JOIN, but unfortunately I could not find the answer.

Greetings, xola

Comment: look for mysql prepared statement https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-prepared-statement.aspx

Comment: Note that this kind of situation is sometimes symptomatic of poor design

Comment: @nbk A prepared statement is not going to help with dynamic table and field names, that will need actually vary from row to row in the query.

Comment: I still would built a procedure with a loop through base tabke  and use prepareed staement to get the data, pumo it into a temp table and select it. This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of design is usually a bad idea, and you cannot dynamically choose a table to join to in the way you are thinking, but it can be done in a crude rather brute force kind of way....

```
SELECT stuff 
   , COALESCE(t2.something, t3.something, ....) AS otherTsomething
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.TableToJoin = "t2" 
   AND t1.JoinValue = CASE t1.FieldToJoin WHEN "a" THEN t2.a WHEN "b" THEN t2.b .... END
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.TableToJoin = "t3" 
   AND t1.JoinValue = CASE t1.FieldToJoin WHEN "a" THEN t3.a WHEN "b" THEN t3.b .... END
;
```

Usually, the appropriate design for this kind of data is to have t2 and t3 reference t1, then it simply becomes...

```
SELECT stuff, COALESCE(t2.something, t3.something, ...) AS otherSomething
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.t1_id
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.id = t3.t1_id
;
```

(For your purposes, this presumes to some degree that only one t2 or t3 will be associated with a t1 record; but that would be hard to enforce, and in general use doesn't really present a problem.)